# embededd application host in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set an application to be the child of my WPF application.
My application has 3 window and I would like all windows to  be childs of the WPF.
I use this code enter code here
main:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndParent);
```

loaded:

```
var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, helper.Handle);
```

It works just for one of the windows.
What should I do to have all windows in child of WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Each control in WinForm has a unique handle, but WPF elements have not, To solve your problem you can put one or more WindowsFormsHost in the window and use handle of them because each WindowsFormsHost also has a unique handle the same as WinForm controls.

Then use SetParent like this :

```
 SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, YourWindowsFormsHost.Handle );
```